# Seperating a string into a list that has nested brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have spent a few hours trying to break this string apparent into a nested list.  However, I have run into multiple road blocks and feel lost.

I have searched Stack Over to see if this question has been answered.  However, I can't find anything that tries to parse a string into a nested list based off brackets.

I wanted to post code, however, every attempted failed with multiple issues.

Here is an example of the string.

```
x = "[XIC(B3.0) ,XIC(B3.1) ,XIC(B3.3)XIC(B3.4) ,[XIC(B3.13) XIC(B3.9)] ,XIC(B3.14) ]XIC(B3.11)XIC(B3.10)XIC(B3.7)[XIC(B3.2) XIC(B3.8) OTE(B3.15) ,OTE(B3.12)] "

output = [[XIC(B3.0) ,XIC(B3.1) ,XIC(B3.3)XIC(B3.4) ,[XIC(B3.13) XIC(B3.9)] ,XIC(B3.14) ], XIC(B3.11)XIC(B3.10)XIC(B3.7),[XIC(B3.2) XIC(B3.8) OTE(B3.15) ,OTE(B3.12)]
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your "output"-assignment  is invalid python. please post a [mre] with your error.We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: Your output appears to be the same as the input, just without quotes. This is not a valid Python literal, and especially not a valid nested list. Please clarify what you are actually trying to do, and what are the requirements for parsing the string. Note also that SO is not a code-writing service - if you have existing code, show it so that we can help you debug it.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please clarify input data?

Here's your input list:

```
[
    XIC(B3.0),
    XIC(B3.1),
    XIC(B3.3)XIC(B3.4),
    [
        XIC(B3.13) XIC(B3.9)
    ],
    XIC(B3.14)
]XIC(B3.11)XIC(B3.10)XIC(B3.7)[XIC(B3.2) XIC(B3.8) OTE(B3.15),
OTE(B3.12)]
```

seems that it lacks some brackets and commas. Does every OTE,XIC segment should be in separate cell?

Here's output you gave:

```
[
    [
        XIC(B3.0),
        XIC(B3.1),
        XIC(B3.3)XIC(B3.4),
        [XIC(B3.13) XIC(B3.9)],
        XIC(B3.14)],
        XIC(B3.11)XIC(B3.10)XIC(B3.7),
        [
            XIC(B3.2) XIC(B3.8) OTE(B3.15), 
            OTE(B3.12)
        ]
```

it also lack brackets.

I would suggest such solution:

```
import re

x = "[XIC(B3.0) ,XIC(B3.1) ,XIC(B3.3)XIC(B3.4) ,[XIC(B3.13) XIC(B3.9)] ,XIC(B3.14) ]XIC(B3.11)XIC(B3.10)XIC(B3.7)[XIC(B3.2) XIC(B3.8) OTE(B3.15) ,OTE(B3.12)] "

def inner_list(in_value, is_debug=False):
    """
    Gets string of "dirty" data and returns list of values
    :in_value str:
    :return list:
    """
    if is_debug: print("In value", in_value)
    no_brackets = re.sub(r'\[|\]|\,', '', temp_list)
    if is_debug: print("Strip brackets", no_brackets)
    return re.split(", |\s", no_brackets)

is_debug = False
# Find all inner lists first
z = re.findall("\[[a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\.\,\s]*\]",x)
sub_list = {}

# Make sub lists look as lists :)
for key,temp_list in enumerate(z):
    sub_list[key] = inner_list(temp_list, is_debug)
    # Function use here is for demo puroses, or for more complex processing. Essentially, function can be replaced with following string:
    # sub_list[key] = re.findall(r"[A-Z]{3}\([A-Z][0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}\)", temp_list)

# Mark sublist locations with tokens
z1 = re.sub(r"\[[a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\.\,\s]*\]", "##",x)
# Split string to list
z3 = re.findall(r"[A-Z]{3}\([A-Z][0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}\)|##", z1)

token_count = 0
resulting_list = []
# Populate resulting list and insert sub_lists in place of ## tokens
for elem in z3:
    if "##" in elem:
            resulting_list.append(sub_list[token_count])
            token_count += 1
    else:
            resulting_list.append(elem)

print(resulting_list)
```

This code results:

```
[
    'XIC(B3.0)',
    'XIC(B3.1)',
    'XIC(B3.3)',
    'XIC(B3.4)',
    [
        'XIC(B3.13)',
        'XIC(B3.9)'
    ],
    'XIC(B3.14)',
    'XIC(B3.11)',
    'XIC(B3.10)',
    'XIC(B3.7)',
    [
        'XIC(B3.2)',
        'XIC(B3.8)',
        'OTE(B3.15)',
        'OTE(B3.12)'
    ]
]
```